# An error occurs on save if a filename of more than a certain number of characters is uploaded

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a strange behaviour when I try to upload a file with more than **186** characters length of filename.

*I get the following error on NotesXSPDocument.save():*

[image]

---

*And the following error when saving using a simple action:*

[image]

---

*Source Code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" computeWithForm="onsave" formName="Files"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload" value="#{document1.Body}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:// kick off round-trip...}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:fileUpload>

    <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload1" displayLastModified="false" value="#{document1.Body}"></xp:fileDownload>

    <xp:button value="Save Document SimpleAction" id="btnSaveDocumentSimpleAction">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:button value="Save Document NotesXSPDocument" id="btnSaveDocumentNotesXSPDocument">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.save();}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

**Hint:** I am working on a Domino Sever 8.5.3 FP6

Thanks in advance for any answer.

---

**UPDATE:**

On the domino server I can find (copy, rename, etc.) the uploaded file, so I can't understand the following error message:

Error while saving document
Could not save the document NEW_c0 NotesException: File C:\TEMP\SYSTEM\notesC78121\xsppers\143\E9DMAJ1VVQ\DominoDoc-231-Body\BCXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCXXXXXXXXXXCxxXXXXXXXXAXXXXXXXXXXBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCXCCXCCCCCCCCCXXXXXXXXXXXCDDABCCCCCCCXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDX.jpg **not found**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting the Windows file path length limit of 256 characters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath

If you need to upload files with such long file names, you should run your Domino server on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. However I am confused about the error message which comes from the domino server. Second: Obviously I have reached the limit of the operating system (255 characters) but on the other hand why I can handle (copy, rename, etc.) the uploaded file on the domino server?

Comment: Domino is unable to get to the file because of the file *path* limit. You can copy the file itself because the file name is below the limit.

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows` individual components of a filename (directories along the path, and the final filename) are limited to 255 characters. I have exceeded this limit.

The length of the following filepath is **256** characters:

> C:\TEMP\SYSTEM\notesC78121\xsppers\143\E9DMAJ1VVQ\DominoDoc-231-Body\BCXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCXXXXXXXXXXCxxXXXXXXXXAXXXXXXXXXXBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCXCCXCCCCCCCCCXXXXXXXXXXXCDDABCCCCCCCXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDX.jpg